# File chooser in a default Cocoa application

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I have created a default [Swift] Cocoa application. I attempted to Ctrl drag from the default Open button in the menu to my View Controller in the assistant editor, but nothing happens.

Is my approach wrong? I assume there is some kind of default file chooser dialog, but I do not know how to make it appear or enable the Open menu item. From the documentation I feel I could make one appear programmatically, but I want to enable the menu button.

My first attempt at an OS X program hit a wall very fast :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, control-Click on Open, and see if it is already attached to a function.  If so, click the **x** to detach it, then try again.

Second, be very sure that the Assistant Editor is presenting the correct file to do the control-Drag.  I have found that I need to manually choose the correct file much of the time.